# Str Function in VBA for Excel adds a character to the string

Tags: string, casting, excel, integer, vba

I am converting an integer to string using the str() function

However, I noticed that the str() function would return an extra character to the string.

For example, `MsgBox(Len(str(1)))` would return 2.

What is the extra character being appended?

Comment: Doug Glancy's quote is correct although I would have added the next line: "Use the Format function to convert numeric values you want formatted as dates, times, or currency or in other user-defined formats. _Unlike Str, the Format function doesn't include a leading space for the sign of number_."  [My italics]

Comment: And if you want to trim that extra blank space, you can always use this `MsgBox (Len(Trim(Str(1))))`

Comment: Use `Cstr(1)` rather than `Str(1)`. Cstr does not add a space.

Answer (score 10):

From Excel 2010 help:

"When numbers are converted to strings, a leading space is always reserved for the sign of number. If number is positive, the returned string contains a leading space and the plus sign is implied."

And sure enough this statement returns True in the debug window:

```
? left(str(1),1) = " "
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to find out:

```
MsgBox(Asc(Right(Str(1),1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17997997/2135406) answer you should use the `format()` function.