# Str adds extra space

Tags: string, excel, vba

```
Dim i As Integer

i = Int((8 - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)

Dim rg As String
Dim con As String

con = Str(i)

rg = "B" & con
MsgBox (rg)
```

This returns "B 4" not "B4 anyone know the issue

Comment: Trim avoids any heading/ending blank-space related problem (con = Trim(Str(i))). I use it always when dealing with strings. Your question is answered below, this is just a generic recommendation :)

Answer (score 19):

Use `Cstr(i)` rather than `Str(i)`. `Cstr` does not add a space.

Comment: +1, Of the various suggestions, this is the most straightforward.

Comment: Str and Cstr do not behave the same if your locale settings uses a different decimal separator than "." Str always uses ".", Cstr uses local decimal separator.

Answer (score 6):

From the Help page for `Str()`

> When numbers are converted to strings, a leading space is always
>   reserved for the sign of number. If number is positive, the returned
>   string contains a leading space and the plus sign is implied.

Answer (score 2):

`Str()` leaves space for the sign.

As Excel has implicit conversion, you can use `rg = "B" & i` and get the range you want

Answer (score 2):

Use format() function ...

```
con = format(i)

rg = "B" & con
MsgBox (rg)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Trim function to remove leading space as under:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim i As Integer

i = Int((8 - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)

Dim rg As String
Dim con As String

con = Str(i)

rg = "B" & Trim(con)
MsgBox (rg)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel Concatonate a string based on the int.

Here's a desciption

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10004244/1504882